# Rename a USB device for static name without udev rule

Tags: linux, usb, udev, ttyusb

I have an Arduino board connected to a `USB` port and recognized by Ubuntu as the `ttyACM0` device. For programming reasons on the Arduino site, the device should be visible on Linux as the `ttyUB0` device.

This trouble could be solved by using `udev` and the rule:

`SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="XXX", ATTRS{idProduct}=="YYY", MODE="0666", SYMLINK+="ttyUSBO"`

written in the `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb-serial.rules`

The Arduino board works with these settings, and everything looks good.

But I want to connect the second device with a `FTDI_FT232_USB_UART` chip. This device is automatically recognized by Ubuntu and registered as the `ttyUSB0` device.

At this point, I have a mix - because I have symlink from Arduino to the `ttyUSB0` and "true" `ttyUSB0` device from the `FTDI` chip. As a result, none of these devices are working correctly.

When I tried to look at the `ttyUSB0`, there was a mix of data from these two devices.

I tried to rename the `ttyUSB0` from the `FTDI` chip by writing another `udev` rule, but this didn't have any effect because I could only create another symlink to the `ttyUSB0` device.

Renaming the `USB` device with the `udev` rules is impossible, according to the [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/udev.html)

I tried to find another way to rename the `USB` device to the static name, e.g., `ttyUSBX`, during connecting but failed.

Can the `FTDI` based chip device static name be given during its connecting or renamed it later so as not to collide with the `ttyUSB0` symlink created for Arduino?

Comment: "For programming reasons on the Arduino site" i'm pretty sure you can just change the name of the device the arduino IDE uses. So fix that, instead of trying to do something complicated, partially impossible.

Comment: You're right. But this is part of some bigger system, and other people make Arduino part - and it is not easy to ask them to adjust the name they used. If I don't find another solution, will try to ask them about this.

Comment: you will have to. Otherwise you'd break other things. Honestly, renaming an ACM device to something that suggests a different serial device type does transport expectations that are *not* true!